# Parse server setup

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

I have setup the parse server on my local machine, following the instruction guide, now what should be my next step as to how to use it to send push notification. Suggest ways to use parse sever, where i can see the functionality of the parse server setup on my machine

Comment: I suggest you don't setup a parse server at all since they're stopping their service in january.

Comment: Zil, they are stopping their cloud service and suggest setting up a server instead.

Comment: I recommend using back4app.com or sashido.io . This service is parse hosting services that save your time.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how to implement push notifications with parse-server : https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Push

Answer (score 0):

To implement push you need to have two things , as you will be using your own server for sending push notifications , you need to go to google app engine and get gcm sender id and gcm server api key. Here is the configuration code that i use for my parse-server.

```
var api = new ParseServer({
        // Debug server
        databaseURI: '',
        cloud: '',
        appId: '',
        masterKey: '',
        clientKey: '',
        restAPIKey: '',
        javascriptKey: '',
        serverURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:1338/parse',
        databaseOptions: {
            poolSize: 50
        },
        push: {
            android: {
                senderId: '', // The Sender ID of GCM
                apiKey: '' // The Server API Key of GCM
            }
        }
    });
```